# get size of everything on timescaledb server

Tags: postgresql, diskspace, timescaledb

I am looking for a way to find the total disk space (or estimate, if exact not possible) used by my timescaledb server using a query as I'm accessing it remotely with the python `sqlalchemy` library.

According to [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/app-psql.html) `\l+` displays all databases in the server along with their info and below is the source code (found with `psql -E`). Would summing over the size column give me the total I'm looking for, or are there additional items it might miss?

```
SELECT d.datname as "Name",
       pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(d.datdba) as "Owner",
       pg_catalog.pg_encoding_to_char(d.encoding) as "Encoding",
       d.datcollate as "Collate",
       d.datctype as "Ctype",
       pg_catalog.array_to_string(d.datacl, E'\n') AS "Access privileges",
       CASE WHEN pg_catalog.has_database_privilege(d.datname, 'CONNECT')
            THEN pg_catalog.pg_size_pretty(pg_catalog.pg_database_size(d.datname))
            ELSE 'No Access'
       END as "Size",
       t.spcname as "Tablespace",
       pg_catalog.shobj_description(d.oid, 'pg_database') as "Description"
FROM pg_catalog.pg_database d
  JOIN pg_catalog.pg_tablespace t on d.dattablespace = t.oid
ORDER BY 1;
```

---

I've written this, but would appreciate any improvements (do I need that WHEN?).

```
SELECT
       SUM(CASE WHEN has_database_privilege(pg_database.datname, 'CONNECT')
              THEN pg_database_size(pg_database.datname)
              ELSE 0
       END) as "Size"
FROM pg_database;
```